# You can send empty messages in chat

Tags: bug, chat

You can send empty messages in chat! Example [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3700635#3700635). You get this by selecting the text box, hitting <kbd>tab</kbd>, then hitting backspace. Please fix it as it's annoying. Also, this does not send spaces, it seems to send empty characters.

(Using ubuntu with firefox)

I just noticed that this also works with mac. I think it's a FF bug.

Comment: I couldn't repro it, since hitting Tab then Backspace navigated the browser to page before... anyway, don't do it.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Can't repro this in chrome, might be a firefox thing

Comment: Repro'd on Firefox. It's ["backspace" control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character?oldformat=true), which reminds me to [this code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52946/backhandedhhhhhhspaces)

Comment: Repro'd only on chat room, not a universal feature. Now I feel like this is really a bug, but current premise is wrong. If you change to "Pressing Tab then Backspace in chat room on FireFox inserts a backspace control character", it'll probably be more well received, but it will invalidate current answer...

Comment: @Andrew well, I did say "or some similar Unicode character" and it's still a Firefox bug, so my answer still holds.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you send Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B), or some similar Unicode character.

This bypass the server side validation, yet is not seen at all in the output.

If you don't put it yourself, something on your side is adding it, nothing SE can do to "fix" it.

Comment: Then SE should fix it!

Comment: How? By hacking into your computer, find whatever is causing it to put the unicode character and fix it? I don't think so.